# anthropomorphic vs. anthropomorphized

Tags: word-usage, variants

When is it most appropriate to use "anthropomorphic" as opposed to "anthropomorphized"? Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: Compare ***electric*** and ***electrified***. The latter form is less common overall, obviously. But it's sometimes useful if you want to call attention to the fact that *something was done* (causing the thing to ***become*** *electric* or *anthropomorphic*)

Comment: Generally the *-ic* suffix is used with what is naturally or currently in a state, while *-ized* specifically applies to cases where a transformation has taken place. Hope that is clear enough. Let's know if you are still unclear.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So that's what I think as well?

Comment: So why am I downvoted twice?

Comment: @Kris: So it would seem. Discounting *electrified = agog*, I think your definition (which is better than mine) exactly covers my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you can use either to describe something non-human with human traits however anthropomorphizing something is **actively** applying human traits to non-human entities.

So for example

> Mickey Mouse, an anthropomorphic rodent that Walt Disney anthropomorphized.
>
> Mickey Mouse, a by Walt Disney anthropomorphized rodent that became anthropomorphic.

As Fumblefinger points out, something can be anthropomorphic by itself without someone having acted upon it

> Here are anthropomorphic Ginseng roots

[image]

Comment: Down voting without comments are useless for all

Comment: Or *Mickey, an **anthropomorphized** rodent that Walt Disney made **anthropomorphic***

Comment: Yes, one is acted upon and the other is the state thereafter

Comment: Google has many instances of ["anthropomorphic root"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22anthropomorphic+root%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=%22anthropomorphic+root%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.12508414j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), few if any of which would refer to something "acted upon". I'd interpret the far less common ["anthropomorphized root"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22anthropomorphic+root%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=%22anthropomorphic+root%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.12508414j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22anthropomorphized+root%22) as "acted upon".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I must agree with mplungjan. "One of Utrecht's most famous daughters is Nijntje, an anthropomorphic rabbit created by the illustrator Dick Bruna..." (NYT) It's used like this all over the place about the creations of Beatrix Potter, Walt Disney, and even Aesop. It's an adjective, synonymous with *anthropomorphous*. I don't understand your objection.

Comment: @medica: My point is that (per my first comment) the distinction is simply a matter of syntax if we restrict ourselves to contexts where something only becomes *anthropomorphic* as a result of being *anthropomorphized*. But some things (ginseng, mandrake roots, etc.) are often described as *anthropomorphic* even when there's no real sense of them being *anthropomorphized* (unless we count "being interpreted by an observer" as a relevant action, as opposed to "being altered by an external force/person").

Comment: I do not disagree with the roots. They are anthropomorphic all by themselves.